# MongoDB on Azure: replSet can't get local.system.replset config

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure

I am using the [MongoDB worker role project](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/deploy-mongodb-worker-roles-in-azure/) to use MongoDB on Azure. I have two separate cloud services, in one of them everything works fine, however in the other, the MongoDB worker role is stuck in a `Busy (Waiting for role to start... Calling OnRoleStart` state.

I connected to one of the MongoDB worker roles and accessed the MongoDB log file and found the following error:

```
[rsStart] replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
```

There are threads on how to fix this normally, but not with Windows Azure. I did not configure anything for the MongoDB worker role (apart from Azure storage connection strings), and it works in another service, so I don't know why it isn't working for this service. Any idea?

Comment: The trace is synched up to Azure Blob Storage. Can you look at them to see what the error is ? Alternately are you able to RDP to the machine to see what is happening? Finally, are both these services on the same storage account? If so make sure they have different RS names

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was trying to host RavenDB in Azure as Worker Role and had lot's of issues with it as well.

Today, I believe it's better to run database the "suggested" way on target platform which is as Windows Service according to this ["Install MongoDB on Windows"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) guide. This way you won't have to deal with Azure-specific issues. To achieve this you can:

1. Use [Azure CmdLets](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/powershell-cmdlets/) along with CsPack.exe to create the package for MondoDB.
2. A solution similiar to [RavenDB Master-Slave reads on Azure](https://github.com/cloudpowerups/cp-azure-samples/tree/master/CP.Azure.Samples.RavenDB) which I posted on GitHub.
3. Sign up for Virtual Machine (beta) on Azure, kick off a machine and install MongoDB manually there.

But I guess the most important question when hosting DB is: where do you plan to store the actual DB?

- Azure's CloudDrive, which is a VHD stored in Cloud Storage, has the worst IO performance possible. Not sufficient for normal DB usage I'd say.
- Ephemeral storage, a Cloud Service local disk space, has perfect IO, but you lose all data once VM is deleted. This means you usually want to make continious or at least regular backups to Cloud Storage, maybe through CloudDrive.
- [Azure VM attached disk](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/) - has better IO than CloudDrive, but still not as good as Ephemeral storage.

As for the actual troubleshooting to your problem. I'd suggest wrapping OnRoleStart with try-catch, writting it to the log, enabling RDP to the box and then connecting and looking into the actual issue right in place. Another alternative is using IntelliTrace, but you need VS Ultimate for that. Also, don't forget that Azure requires usage of Local Resources if your app needs to make writes to the disk.